# Why would two distinctly separate custom fields share the same options?

Tags: custom-fields

Why would two distinctly separate custom fields {Constituent Info and Contribution Info} share the same options? How do I go about separating them? If I try to delete any option I get this notification.

These Multiple Choice Options are shared by the following custom fields: Marital Status, Appeal

Comment: Would I create another option group and tie it to one of the custom fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Civi allows you to set the same Options to be available on multiple fields. You do this by selecting an existing set of Options when creating the field, rather than creating a new set.

If you require different options for the second field then yes set that field to "Create a new set of options"

However that will mess with any existing data you may have. I would suggest you create a new Field with the new set of options, then, if required, you may be able to figure out how to review the existing data and use Batch Update via Profile to add the relevant data to the new field.

Comment: I did create a new custom set of options with a new name - then I unshared the original filed title name with the inappropriate option set and re-associated it with the correct option set.
Thanks for this information.